# 2 variables aren't being compensated for time whilist offline, where as one other variable is

Tags: java, android

This is supposed to basically make the user's variables continue to increment whilist offline. $money is working fine, but it's not adding anything to $employeeupgrade1level or $employerupgrade1level and I've been trying to figure out why for hours. I'm not sure whether I'm simply overlooking something or the problem is more than that, but the the full source code's here: http://125.63.48.169/other%20stuff/business%20builder/code.txt
Posting whole script because it's probably full of things I'm overlooking, and it'd be too much to put here.

```
    public void timer() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                $money = $money + $employeeupgrade1earnings;
                $employercounter = (600 / $employerupgrade1level)*18;
                $managercounter = (600 / $managerupgrade1level)*18;

                if ($employerupgrade1level >= 1) {
                    $employeeupgrade1level = $employeeupgrade1level + (1 / $employercounter);
                    $employeeupgrade1earnings = $employeeupgrade1level / 10;
                }
                if ($managerupgrade1level >= 1) {
                    $employerupgrade1level = $employerupgrade1level + (1 / $managercounter);
                    $employerupgrade1earnings = $employerupgrade1level;
                }
                if ($cantafford == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Can't afford this! You only have " + df.format($money) + " BB!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    $cantafford = 0;

                }
                if ($isonmainpage == 0) {
                    TextView cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeupgradecost);
                    TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeupgradeamount);
                    TextView earnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeupgradeearnings);
                    earnings.setText("You earn " + df.format($employeeupgrade1earnings) + " BBs every second.");
                    cost.setText("Costs " + df.format($employeeupgrade1cost) + " Business Bucks.");
                    amount.setText("You have " + noDecimals.format($employeeupgrade1level) + " casual workers.");
                    TextView cost2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerupgradecost);
                    TextView amount2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerupgradeamount);
                    TextView earnings2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerupgradeearnings);
                    earnings2.setText("You earn "+$employerupgrade1level+" casual worker(s) every 3 hours.");
                    cost2.setText("Costs " + df.format($employerupgrade1cost) + " Business Bucks.");
                    amount2.setText("You have " + noDecimals.format($employerupgrade1level) + " casual employers.");


                }
                updatemoney();
                timer();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }


  public void offlineEarnings() {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        lastTime = sharedpreferences.getString("currentTime", currentTime);
        currentTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        timeDifference = (Double.valueOf(currentTime)) - Double.valueOf(lastTime);
        timeDifferenceMinutes = (timeDifference / 1000) / 60;
        timeDifferenceSeconds = Double.valueOf(timeDifference) / 1000;
        $offlineMoneyEarned = ($employeeupgrade1level / 10) * timeDifferenceSeconds;
        $money = $money + $offlineMoneyEarned;
        $managercounter = (600 / $managerupgrade1level)*18;
        $employercounter = (600 / $employerupgrade1level) * 18;

        if ($employercounter > 0) {
            Double $offlineEmployeesEarned = Double.valueOf(Math.round(timeDifferenceSeconds / $employercounter));
            $employeeupgrade1level = $offlineEmployeesEarned + $employeeupgrade1level;
        } else $offlineEmployeesEarned = 0;
        if ($managercounter > 0) {
            Double $offlineEmployeesEarned = Double.valueOf(Math.round(timeDifferenceSeconds / $managercounter));
            $managerupgrade1level = $offlineEmployeesEarned + $managerupgrade1level;
        } else $offlineEmployersEarned = 0;


        drawEarnings();
    }
    public void drawEarnings(){
        if (debugmode == 1) {
            SimpleDateFormat DateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            //get string
            String timeSinceLastPlayed = "Time since you last played: " + noDecimals.format(timeDifferenceSeconds) +" seconds ("+ df.format((timeDifferenceSeconds/60)) + " minutes or " + df.format(((timeDifferenceSeconds / 60)/60)) + " hours.)";
            String dateLastPlayed = "Date of last session: " + DateFormatter.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(lastTime)));

            String offlineMoneyEarned = "Money earned since last session: " + df.format($offlineMoneyEarned) + ".";
            String offlineEmployeesEarned = "Employees earned since last session: " + $offlineEmployeesEarned + ". ";
            String offlineEmployersEarned = "Employers earned since last session: " + $offlineEmployersEarned + ". ";
            //get textview
            TextView tvTimeSinceLastPlayed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeSinceLastPlayed);
            TextView tvDateLastPlayed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateLastPlayed);
            TextView tvOfflineMoneyEarned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offlineMoneyEarned);
            TextView tvOfflineEmployeesEarned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offlineEmployeesEarned);
            TextView tvOfflineEmployersEarned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offlineEmployersEarned);
            //set text string
            tvTimeSinceLastPlayed.setText(timeSinceLastPlayed);
            tvDateLastPlayed.setText(dateLastPlayed);
            tvOfflineEmployeesEarned.setText(offlineEmployeesEarned);
            tvOfflineMoneyEarned.setText(offlineMoneyEarned);
            tvOfflineEmployersEarned.setText(offlineEmployersEarned);
            //make text visible
            tvOfflineEmployeesEarned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvOfflineMoneyEarned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvDateLastPlayed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvTimeSinceLastPlayed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvOfflineEmployersEarned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    }




    public void buyEmployeeUpgrade1(View view) {
        if ($money >= $employeeupgrade1cost) {
            $money = $money - $employeeupgrade1cost;

            $employeeupgrade1level = $employeeupgrade1level + 1;
            $employeeupgrade1earnings = $employeeupgrade1level / 10;
            $allupgrades = $employeeupgrade1earnings + $allupgrades;


            double $randomCost = 1.05 + (1.4 - 1.05) * random.nextDouble();
            $employeeupgrade1cost = $employeeupgrade1cost * $randomCost;

            //employee upgrade
            TextView cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeupgradecost);
            TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeupgradeamount);
            TextView earnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeupgradeearnings);
            earnings.setText("You earn " + noDecimals.format($employeeupgrade1earnings) + " BBs every second.");
            cost.setText("Costs " + df.format($employeeupgrade1cost) +" Business Bucks.");
            amount.setText("You have " + noDecimals.format($employeeupgrade1level) + " casual workers.");

        }
        else $cantafford = 1;
    }


    public void buyEmployerUpgrade1(View view) {
        if ($money >= $employerupgrade1cost) {
            $money = $money - $employerupgrade1cost;

            $employerupgrade1level = $employerupgrade1level + 1;
            double $randomCost = 1.05 + (1.4 - 1.05) * random.nextDouble();
            $employerupgrade1cost = $employerupgrade1cost * $randomCost;
            $employercounter = (600 / $employerupgrade1level) * 18;
            $employerupgrade1earnings = $employerupgrade1level;


            TextView cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerupgradecost);
            TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerupgradeamount);
            TextView earnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employerupgradeearnings);
            earnings.setText("You earn "+$employerupgrade1level+" casual worker(s) every 3 hours.");
            cost.setText("Costs " + df.format($employerupgrade1cost) + " Business Bucks.");
            amount.setText("You have " + noDecimals.format($employerupgrade1level) + " casual employers.");
        } else $cantafford = 1;
    }

    public void buyManagerUpgrade1(View view) {
        if ($money >= $managerupgrade1cost) {
            $money = $money - $managerupgrade1cost;

            $managerupgrade1level = $managerupgrade1level + 1;
            double $randomCost = 1.05 + (1.4 - 1.05) * random.nextDouble();
            $managerupgrade1cost = $managerupgrade1cost * $randomCost;
            $managercounter = (600 / $managerupgrade1level) * 18;
            $managerupgrade1earnings = $managerupgrade1level;


            TextView cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.managerupgradecost);
            TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.managerupgradeamount);
            TextView earnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.managerupgradeearnings);
            earnings.setText("You earn "+noDecimals.format($managerupgrade1level)+"casual employer(s) every 3 hours.");
            cost.setText("Costs " + df.format($managerupgrade1cost) + " Business Bucks.");
            amount.setText("You have " + noDecimals.format($managerupgrade1level) + " casual managers.");
        } else $cantafford = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have dollar signs in your variables? Are you missing PHP?

Comment: it makes it easier for me to distinguish between ints/doubles vs everything else since this has lots and lots of ints/variables in it it can get confusing, for me anyway

Comment: Well it makes it harder for Java programmers to distinguish things. You're also doing other things to make the code harder to read, such as `$variable = $variable + 1;` instead of the idiomatic `$variable++;`. You're also treating ints as booleans, as with your `if($isonmainpage == 0)`. I'd advise you to write a simple test for the relevant code, to see if the (ill named) variables are acting as you think they should be.

Comment: As well as the suggestions @Kayaman provided, consider breaking your code into more manageable methods that clearly demonstrate your intent. You'll be able to unit test better and hopefully flush out the buggy code more easily. In any event, if you can do a little housekeeping on it I'd be happy to help out.

Comment: yeah, I'm like extremely new to android/java so I'm not surprised it's unoptimized. I tried using if(isonmainpage = true) and but it refused to work (at the start of the code I did public boolean isonmainpage = true aswell) so I stuck with using ints as booleans. If you want to see all the code, here's a link: http://125.63.48.169/other%20stuff/business%20builder/code.txt

Comment: Okay, so it's fixed. Answer is below, but I would really like to know what kind of housekeeping/optimizing my code could use, because it seems it would help me heaps.

Answer (score 0):

So I've fixed it. New offlineEarnings() code is this;

```
public void offlineEarnings() {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        lastTime = sharedpreferences.getString("currentTime", currentTime);
        currentTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        timeDifference = (Double.valueOf(currentTime)) - Double.valueOf(lastTime);
        timeDifferenceMinutes = (timeDifference / 1000) / 60;
        timeDifferenceSeconds = Double.valueOf(timeDifference) / 1000;
        $offlineMoneyEarned = ($employeeupgrade1level / 10) * timeDifferenceSeconds;
        $money = $money + $offlineMoneyEarned;


        if ($employerupgrade1level > 0) {
            $offlineEmployeesEarned = (Double.valueOf(Math.round(timeDifferenceSeconds) / $employercounter));
            $employeeupgrade1level = $offlineEmployeesEarned + $employeeupgrade1level;
        } else $offlineEmployeesEarned = 0;
        if ($managerupgrade1level > 0) {
            $offlineEmployersEarned = (Double.valueOf(Math.round(timeDifferenceSeconds) / $managercounter));
            $employerupgrade1level = $offlineEmployeesEarned + $employerupgrade1level;
        } else $offlineEmployersEarned = 0;
        drawEarnings();
    }
```